# Finding an right IP of a web-site

Tags: dns, ip

I have tried to send a DNS packet to get an IP of some web-site.

In some cases, like google, the IP was right and when i typed it in the url line it sent me to google.

But in other cases (for example : stackoverflow.com) its gave me an IP that didin't linked to the web-site.

To be sure that my packet is right, i tried to do `Nslookap` in the command line, and the result was the same.

So i cant find the right IP adress of a web-site.
There is the message that appear when I'm trying to enter stakoverflow

```
Fastly error: unknown domain: 151.101.65.69.
Please check that this domain has been added to a service.
```

Comment: Not suitable for Stack Overflow, try next time Super user for this type of questions

Answer (score 1):

You (generally speaking) can not open the website just by entering the IP address in your browser's address bar because web servers (and possibly many other network components that are between you and the web server) often do not host only one web site on that IP address so they rely on exact domain name typed in address bar to serve the right content.

Answer (score 0):

I think, it's caused by yours internet restriction. Try to contact your ISP (your internet provider) about this problem. He will probably know more about cause of this problem.

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: you need a host header.

Long answer: Since HTTP/1.1 introduced in 1997 (and then updated in 1999 and in 2014), the request needs a `host` header. That allows the web server to route a request to a corresponding server configuration, a `virtual server` in Apache speak. Some servers don't have this configured and is allowing requests to any host to be served from the same web server configuration.

HTTP/1.1 also allowed multi-tenant proxies, as Fastly, to exist in the Internet. Fastly is a CDN - content delivery network - that allows to cache websites content on closer to users and deliver it locally (faster than from a cloud or a colo, thus the name).

When you're not specifying the domain for the request, it looks like your client (or a library) is using the IP address as the host header. That's why the response from Fastly talks about domain: `unknown domain: 151.101.65.69`.

While Fastly do support `service pinning` to a dedicated IP address, which would have worked for your request - it doesn't look like stackoverflow is using the feature as they might not need it.